# $\left( k, n \right)$ symmetry?

Tags: combinatorics, bell-numbers, fubini-tonelli-theorems

As background: there are $k!$ strict orders on the set $K = \left\{ 1, \ldots k \right\}$.  Under symmetry, each order occurs with probability $\tfrac{1}{k!}$.

Now consider the set of weak orders on $K$.  When $k=2$, this has three elements: $\left( 1|2 \right)$, $\left( 2|1 \right)$ and $\left( 12 \right)$.  For general $k$, its cardinality is the $k^{\text{th}}$ Fubini or ordered Bell number, and is indexed by the OEIS as [A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670).

I want a notion of symmetry for this set of weak orders.  Specifically, I want it to have the property that the probability factor associated with each term in an order depends only on the number of elements in that term (e.g. one or two in the $k=2$ example above).

Concretely: let each $i \in K$ be uniformly and independently distributed over a set of $n$ 'slots'.  Thus:

- when $n=1$, the element $\left\{ \left\{ 1, \ldots, k \right\} \right\}$ has probability one: all elements of $K$ are assigned to the same slot.
- when $n \rightarrow \infty$, we collapse to the set of strict orders, each of which with probability $\tfrac{1}{k!}$: each element of $K$ is assigned to a unique slot.

I would like to know these probabilities for any positive integers $k$ and $n$.

For example:

- when $k=2$, $p_{(12)} = \tfrac{1}{n}$, while $p_{(1|2)} = p_{(2|1)} = \tfrac{1}{2n} (n-1)^+$, where $x^+ = \max \left\{ 0, x \right\}$; and
- when $k=3$, $p_{(123)} = \tfrac{1}{n^2}$, $p_{(1|23)} = p_{(12|3)} = \tfrac{1}{2n^2} (n-1)^+$ and $p_{(1|2|3)} = \tfrac{1}{6n^2} (k-1)^+ (k-2)^+$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "probability factor associated with each term in an order depends only on the number of elements in that term" Do you mean that you want to count in how many ways can we put the $k$ numbers into the $n$ blocks with order?

Comment: You found where I'm stuck. I tried a Hasse diagram (for $k=3$, a cube). With strict orders, travel is along the edges; giving factor $q_1$ to each yields, e.g. the probability of $\emptyset - \left\{1\right\}$ is $q_1/3q_1 = 1/3$.

With weak orders travel is also across faces (two arrive together) & through the centre (three). I wanted $q_2$ and $q_3$ factors for these, respectively.

But this introduces dependence, contradicting the UID assumption: two together force the third to arrive alone.

So, two goals: (1) yours, counting the ways; (2) if I can, connecting to Hasse diagram.

Comment: I am afraid your comment confuse me even more. If i understand correctly, counting them is $n!{k\brace n}$ with the Stirling number. In that way you are grouping together all the ones that have same number of boxes.

Comment: You're helping clarify my thinking: thank you.

Given $k=3, n=2$: (i) enumerate orders, here $|123$, $1|23$, $12|3$, $123|$, $13|2$, $2|13$, $23|1$ and $3|12$; (ii) 'flatten' [?] them to ordinal, here combining $|123$ and $123|$; (iii) assign probabilities based on counting, here $p_{1|23} = p_{12|3} = 1/8$ and $p_{123} = 1/4$. In this example, I _think_ the formula for step (i) is: $2 S(3,1) + (3-1)! (3-2)! S(3,2)$.

For general $k, n$, I want to keep track of where empty boxes occur. e.g. for $k=n=4$, $12||3|4$ and $12|3||4$ are enumerated separately in step (i).

Comment: An easier formula for (i) is $n^k$ because, apparently, you also have cases in which the block can be empty. This is equivalent to count functions from $[k]$ to $[n].$ If i understand correctly "flatten them" is take out the order of the block? What i really do not understand is how you assigned a probability. I think i got an email from you. Perhaps i will read and discuss over there.